# Pre-populate fields using visual flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I am creating an opportunity by clicking on new opportunity related list button on campaign.I am using url hacking to pre-populate certain fields. The problem is as the number of fields to pre-populate becomes bigger the more clumsy the url becomes.I am wondering if this can be done easily with flows ? if yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done with flows. You need a flow and a button. The button will launch the flow and it can also send in variables just like you do with the URL hacking. The flow would start with a lot of variables being sent in, then probably contain a screen to get any additional values and then a record create element.

So overall, it's still big and clunky, but it's now in a supported feature.